# remove unwanted objects from Yandex Maps, where the coordinates of the objects are updated every 5 seconds

Tags: android, object, yandex

I have almost 50 cars in my Yandex Maps, where coordinates of the objects are taken from API,i have to draw cars by their location and update coordinates every 5 secs.  When first time I run app, it is ok, but after 5 secs it draws another object(car) next to the old one, and after some seconds it shows many cars in my map related to one car. 
    My question is how to delete objects that were drawn before and leave just last updated object. 
    Thanks in advance! I'm new in android:)
     import java.io.BufferedReader;
        import java.io.IOException;
        import java.io.InputStreamReader;
        import java.net.MalformedURLException;
        import java.net.URL;
        import java.net.URLConnection;
        import java.util.ArrayList;
        import java.util.List;
        import java.util.Timer;
        import java.util.TimerTask;

```
    import org.json.JSONArray;
    import org.json.JSONException;
    import org.json.JSONObject;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.res.Resources;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;
    import ru.yandex.yandexmapkit.*;
    import ru.yandex.yandexmapkit.overlay.Overlay;
    import ru.yandex.yandexmapkit.overlay.OverlayItem;
    import ru.yandex.yandexmapkit.overlay.balloon.BalloonItem;
    import ru.yandex.yandexmapkit.utils.GeoPoint;

    public class BalloonOverlayActivity extends Activity {
        MapController mMapController;
        OverlayManager mOverlayManager;

        Timer timer;
        List<Car> listCars = new ArrayList<Car>();

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setTitle(R.string.app_name);

            setContentView(R.layout.sample);

            final MapView mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map);

            mMapController = mapView.getMapController();
            mOverlayManager = mMapController.getOverlayManager();
            mOverlayManager.getMyLocation().setEnabled(false);

            mMapController.setPositionAnimationTo(new GeoPoint(51.0708045959473,71.3955688476563));

            timer = new Timer();
            timer.schedule(new MyTimerTask(), 1000, 5000);
        }

        public void showObject() {
            Resources res = getResources();
            Overlay overlay = new Overlay(mMapController);
            List<OverlayItem> carsItem = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();

            for (Car c : listCars) {
                final OverlayItem car = new OverlayItem(
                        new GeoPoint(c.lat, c.lon),
                        res.getDrawable(R.drawable.car));
                BalloonItem balloonCar = new BalloonItem(this, car.getGeoPoint());
                balloonCar.setText("Машина "+c.num);
                car.setBalloonItem(balloonCar);
                overlay.addOverlayItem(car);
                carsItem.add(car);
            }
            System.out.println(overlay.getOverlayItems().size());
            mOverlayManager.addOverlay(overlay);
        }

        public void getData() {
            listCars.clear();
            try {
                URL komandir = new URL("http://google.kz........");
                URLConnection tc = komandir.openConnection();
                Log.d("connection", tc+"");
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        tc.getInputStream()));
                String line="";
                String message="";
                while ((line =in.readLine()) != null) {
                    message=message+line;
                    Log.d("message", message);
                }
                JSONObject main=new JSONObject(message);
                JSONObject data=main.getJSONObject("data");
                JSONArray array = data.getJSONArray("crews_coords");
                for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject object = (JSONObject) array.get(i);

                    listCars.add(new Car(object.getInt("crew_id"), object
                            .getString("crew_code"), object.getDouble("lon"), object
                            .getDouble("lat")));
                }
                showObject();
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        class MyTimerTask extends TimerTask {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                getData();
            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

// Removes all markers, overlays, and polylines from the map.

```
googleMap.clear();
markerList.clear();
```